# Method for knowing if two functions, defined using $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, $\operatorname{abs}()$, and $\operatorname{round}()$, are equivalent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given two functions $f_1()$ and $f_2()$ that only use $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, $\operatorname{abs}()$, and $\operatorname{round}()$, how can one prove or disprove that $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ for any $x$.

Comment: There is no way to prove or disprove that because crucial information is missing. A function $f\colon A\to B$ is not just the mapping rule, it is the triple $(A,B,f)$ where $A$ is the domain, $B$ the codomain and $f$ the mapping rule. The functions $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $g\colon\mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$ given by $f(x)=g(x)=|x|$ satisfy $f(x)=g(x)$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$, but they are not the same function because their codomains are different.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very general, there is not an unique way to solve this type of equation. It depends on the functions, if they are additive, moltiplicative etc...
The only ways I can think of are:

1. Prove that $f_1(x)-f_2(x)=0$
2. Prove that $f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ is constant (for example with derivatives), than evaluate it in a easy point, if in that point is equal to $0$ and you proved it is constant, it is equal to $0$ everywhere.
3. Prove that $\dfrac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}=1$ almost everywhere (for $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f_2(x)\neq 0\}$)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. In order to do this, we follow a simple method to simplify a function.

1. Modify the equation till one side equals one
2. Reduce all fractions and multiply all groups of numbers
3. Round(x)y can not be simplified to Round(xy), but Round(x) + y can be simplified to Round(x + y)
4. abs(x)y can't be simplified for variables or for negative numbers, but positive numbers are fine
5. abs(x) + y and abs(x) - y can't be simplified

From this, you can compare any two equations and see if they are equal.

Comment: As written, this is false, especially (2). For example, take the functions $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x-1}$ and $g(x)=1$. Your method implies that those two are the same function, yet $f$ is not defined on $x=1$.

Comment: But f(x)=x−1/x−1 and g(x)=1 are the same, aren't they?

Comment: They're not. A function is not just the mapping rule, it is the triple $(A,B,f)$ where $A$ is the domain, $B$ the codomain and $f$ the mapping rule. The mapping rule $x\mapsto \frac{x-1}{x-1}$ can't have $1$ in its domain but the mapping rule $x\mapsto 1$ can.

Comment: You mean because  f(1)= 1-1/1-1 is undefined? I thought 0/0 could be defined in certain cases given enough information, isn't this enough info to know f(1) = 1?

Comment: The expression 0/0 can not be defined, no matter how much information you have. If you try to define it as $\frac 00=1$, then $\frac 00\cdot x = 1\cdot x$ and then $\frac 00=x$, so every number is equal to $\frac 00$, therefore every number is equal to every other number, which is clearly nonsense.

Comment: if 0/0 = 1, and you multiply both sides by x, then the information has changed and the 0/0 will no longer equal 1 but x.

Comment: No, that's not true, that's not how rules of arithmetic work. If $Y$ represents any expression, then first setting $Y=1$ and then multiplying both sides by some non-zero $x$ doesn't mean that $Y$ stops being equal to $1$. It is very much still equal to $1$ since $Yx=x$ implies $(Y-1)x=0$.

Comment: I'm saying 5(0/0) doesn't equal (0/0)  0/0 = 1 and 0/0 = 5 are different equations.

Comment: Yes, 0/0 = 1 and 0/0 = 5 would be different equations. The point is that the consequence of those two equations is that $1=5$. The reason why 0/0 is left undefined is precisely because many inconsistencies pop up if you try to apply any sort of mathematics to it. I am not sure why you are insisting on the opposite, this is a well digested topic.